# Can't add plugin run/debug configuration in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to modify an existing IntelliJ IDEA plugin as a step toward building my own. I chose [Front End Alignment](https://github.com/jmulieri/front-end-alignment), opened it in IntelliJ IDEA, added the IntelliJ Community Edition SDK, and built the project successfully. But when I try to add a Plugin Run/Debug Configuration (to verify that I can debug a plugin) the "Use classpath of module" dropdown contains only "[None]", and I get:

```
Run Configuration Error: No plugin module specified for configuration
```

Project Structure > Project Settings > Modules shows that `front-end-alignment` is a known module.

How can I run this sample plugin in the debugger?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import and run existing plugins from intellij community edition repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278440/how-to-import-and-run-existing-plugins-from-intellij-community-edition-repo)

Comment: I thought that question was different from mine because the solution involved changing `MODULE_JAVA` to `MODULE_PLUGIN` but now I see that it is the same issue. So my real question is, how do I follow the time-honored strategy of "find a working example and modify it" to build my own plugin?